# need rewrite nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, uri

I'm having URLs like:

```
index.php?q=123&w=456&e=789
```

and I need to rewrite them in something like:

```
index/123/456/789
```

without using "if".

So far I've tried:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/index.php\?q=(.*)&w=(.*)&e=(.*)$ /index/$1/$2/$3;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't without using `if`.

The long answer is regex in the [`rewrite`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) syntax only matchs the URI.

Try something like this:

```
    location /index.php {
        if ($args ~ "^q=(.*)&w=(.*)&e=(.*)") {
            set $arg_q $1;
            set $arg_w $2;
            set $arg_e $3;
            rewrite_log on;
        rewrite ^ /index/$arg_q/$arg_w/$arg_e last;
        }
    }
```